# Common first term and difference in 3 arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $AP(a,d)$ denote the set of all the term of an infinite arithmetic progression with first term a and common difference d>0. If $AP(1,3)\ \cap AP(2,5)\ \cap AP(3,7)=AP(a,d)$ then find the value of a+d.

My approach

$1 + \left( {{n_1} - 1} \right)3 = X$

$2 + \left( {{n_2} - 1} \right)5 = X$

$3 + \left( {{n_3} - 1} \right)7 = X$

$1 + \left( {{n_1} - 1} \right)3 = 2 + \left( {{n_2} - 1} \right)5 = 3 + \left( {{n_3} - 1} \right)7 \Rightarrow 3{n_1} - 2 = 5{n_2} - 3 = 7{n_3} - 4 = X$

${n_1} = \frac{{X + 2}}{3};{n_2} = \frac{{X + 3}}{5};{n_3} = \frac{{X + 4}}{7}$

We need to find the value where $n_1, n_2,n_3$ are integer and through excel I found the first term as 52.

How do we calculate the first term a=52, d=LCM(3,5,7)=105

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is. Your working seems correct to me. $a = 52$ and $d = 105$, so $a+ d = 157.$ What's the issue?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I’m guessing they want to know how to find the first term without using excel.

Comment: Not they but I , The formula is correct I entered it into excel and then found the correct answer but the same need to be solved mathematically

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say, "the same need to be solved mathematically".

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi ‘They’ is used when referring to another person. For your problem, using the fact that each of those three expressions must be an integer might help.

Comment: This is a question of JEE advanced Paper 1 (2019) . The question I copied as it is mentioned in the paper, The official answer key states that the solution a+d=157

Comment: Look up to the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n_1,n_2,n_3$ must be integers, which only happens when $$X=3p+1=5q+2=7r+3$$ for $p,q,r  \in \mathbb Z$. This means $$3p=5q+1=7r+2 $$ The easiest way to proceed from here is to consider $7r+2$,it needs to be a multiple of $3$ and one more than a multiple of $5$. Since $7r+2 \equiv r+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, you need $r\equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Then it is quick and easy to check $r=1,4,7$ and $7$ is the smallest $r$ that meets all the conditions. So, $$a=X=7(7)+3 =52$$